# Value of type has no member - defined in first and destination controller

Tags: swift, floating-point, mkmapview, segue, viewcontroller

I have two floats to be sent to my destination controller in a prepareForSegue function. I have my variables set up in both variables but I am encountering the above error.

```
 if segue.identifier == "secondmapsegue"
    {
        let destination = segue.destination as! MapsView
       let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        var lat: Float
        var long: Float

        if index.row == 0 {
            lat = MSULandMarks[(indexPath?.row)!].f1
            long = MSULandMarks[(indexPath?.row)!].f2
        }
        else if index.row == 1 {
            lat = MSUFrats[(indexPath?.row)!].f1
            long = MSUFrats[(indexPath?.row)!].f2
        }
        else
        {
            lat = MSUSoro[(indexPath?.row)!].f1
            long = MSUSoro[(indexPath?.row)!].f2
  }
          destination.latitude = lat
           destination.longitude = long
        }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   var latitude: Float
    var longitude: Float
```

Update 1:
The solution selected below was the solution! The slight confusion on my end was the the Xcode suggestion of adding an intial value to the latitude and longitude in my destination controller like so,

```
 var latitude: Float = 0.0
 var longitude: Float = 0.0
```

Don't fret, simply accept the recommendation and continue with your project. Assuming your lat. and long. have values, the 0.0 values will be replaced with your real values.

Comment: just for info : you can use optional if you dont want to give the variable an initial value

Comment: Also a valid suggestion, thanks, Stud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the following snippet is from the destination controller `MapsView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   var latitude: Float
   var longitude: Float
}
```

You need to declare your variables outside your `viewDidLoad` function, like this:

```
var latitude: Float
var longitude: Float

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Comment: That was the solution, thank you! I'll add a note regarding the slight confusion when I initially tried it.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.